# Тестовое окружение Android

Tags: android

Всем привет, возник вопрос, и я не могу найти внятного ответа в сети интернет. Где и как работают UI тесты под Android. Попробую уточнить. Я понимаю, что все это дело выполняется Android устройством, например, при момощи рекордера Espresso. Но тут возникает вопрос, при выполнении тестов может возникнуть потребность создания файлов удаления и подобных небезопасных действий. Вот, например, я запустил тест, который создает в памяти устройства файл под названием file.txt. Но если я запущу тест повторно, то он провалится? Слышал, что для этого необходимо создавать некие тестовые окружения. Пожалуйста, посоветуйте литературу на эту тему или укажите на то, в чем я не прав.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

если вы пишете тесты, нужно писать к ним и код, который будет создавать вокруг приложения "исходное состояние".

вот [здесь](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing),например, метод обозначен директивой `@Before`, которая говорит, что метод будет выполняться до каждого теста, как написано в [доке](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html).

в NUnit, который использую я, есть `[SetUp]` и `[TearDown]`, которые выполняются непосредственно до и после каждого теста, отмеченного директивой `[Test]`.
из литературы могу посоветовать только примеры к тому тестовому фреймворку, который Вы хотите использовать, и апи к нему.

самый кайф - создать 1 функцию и написать к ней кучу хитрых тесткейсов. таким образом, будет выполняться сначала before или setup, затем метод с i-м кейсом, затем after или teardown.
рекомендую почитать [хабр](https://habr.com/post/120101/), особенно часть про `Parameterized`